# In Excel how can I follow a Mailto Hyperlink without using mouse?

Tags: microsoft-excel, email

I have this in cell B2:

```
=HYPERLINK("MAILTO:"&R2&"&subject="&B2&"?BCC="&C2&"&body="&D2,"Send Email")
```

If I left-click on this link it opens up an email in my default mail program (Outlook).

I want to be able to 'follow' this link without using the mouse, in other words I need a keyboard shortcut or a macro which would essentially simulate a left mouse click. I only need to do this for the highlighted cell or the active cell.

I'm using Excel 2016 on a Windows 10 machine, 64 bit.
I'm new to Macros, so I could use some specific help.

Answer (score 1):

The menu key simulates a right mouse click.  To avoid using the mouse:
Navigate to the cell.

Press the Menu key. 
Select Open HyperLink.

[image]

Comment: Hit the hamburger key!